# File system goes read-only on NVMe SSD seemingly at random

Tags: filesystems, ssd, crash, readonly

I am currently running a somewhat fresh Kubuntu 22.04 install on a relatively new M.2 NVMe drive.

However, I have a problem where my computer drive (I think) turns read only, causing the system to sort of crash. When I first installed the system, this would happen very frequently until I applied the `pcie_aspm=off` fix to the /etc/default/grub file:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"`. This made it happen less frequently.

This issue happens on all the previous systems I've tried to install on this drive, with most of the same symptoms, i.e. some icons disappearing, apps breaking, chromium tabs displaying "aw snap," and in particular, libreoffice gives a "filesystem read only" error when trying to save. One thing different from similar errors though, is that when I reboot the computer manually (holding power button) it goes back to normal for a while, while some seem to have problems booting afterwards. Then it happens again some time later. I can provide more details if needed, e.g. hardware, syslog entries, etc.
Does anyone have a permanent solution to this?

Not a computer whiz, but I do know some.

Comment: This looks like a HW bug. This looks very similar to https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216709 but I'm far from sure you could be hitting the same bug. Please try kernel 6.0.9 and if you're still affected it makes sense to file a new bug report.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons for a file system to go read only: either the metadata is inconsistent in a way that the file system driver can detect (for example, a block number being past the end of the device, or a block being referenced that is marked as free), or the SSD itself going into its failsafe mode, where it becomes read only at block level.

File system errors should clear up on reboot, because the last thing the file system driver will do is set an error flag "this file system needs to be checked", which will cause `fsck` to perform a full check.

The full check will try to automatically correct errors, and if it detects any problems that might cause data to be deleted, that check fails, and the init system should drop you into an emergency shell, where you can run fsck a second time in "manual" mode.

If the SSD itself switches to read-only mode, that is a last-resort "please salvage your data now" function. The write error caused by this will *also* cause the file system to go read-only as a result, but it will not be able to write the error marker, and the next boot therefore does *not* run a full filesystem check.

So if the system boots normally, and/or the errors persist after boot I would exchange the SSD.