# FileSystem becomes read-only on Samsung HDD

Tags: hard-disk, hardware, corruption

I have a issue with my btrfs filesystem it boots fine, but some time during usage while running some programs it suddenly
gives this error in the terminal.

```
I/O error brfs unable to open /dev/sda5 read only file system
```

with this i won't be able to mount or reboot my PC due to this

what I have done:
sudo btrfs check /dev/sda5

```
Opening filesystem to check...
WARNING: filesystem mounted, continuing because of --force
Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb5
UUID: 0cbf5d8d-2c36-437d-b7e5-984f60ed315a
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space tree
[4/7] checking fs roots
parent transid verify failed on 18143887360 wanted 67089 found 67230
parent transid verify failed on 18143887360 wanted 67089 found 67230
parent transid verify failed on 18143887360 wanted 67089 found 67230
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 18143887360 wanted 67089 found 67230
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 18143887360 wanted 67089 found 67230
Ignoring transid failure
root 4357 inode 3926866 errors 400, nbytes wrong
root 4357 inode 3926867 errors 2001, no inode item, link count wrong
    unresolved ref dir 303 index 34213 namelen 9 name libltdl.a filetype 1 errors 4, no inode ref
root 4357 inode 3926868 errors 2001, no inode item, link count wrong
    unresolved ref dir 257165 index 310 namelen 7 name ltdl.m4 filetype 1 errors 4, no inode ref

root 4357 inode 3927085 errors 2001, no inode item, link count wrong
    unresolved ref dir 303 index 34275 namelen 13 name libGeoIP.so.1 filetype 7 errors 4, no inode ref
root 4357 inode 3927087 errors 2001, no inode item, link count wrong
    unresolved ref dir 31885 index 4433 namelen 12 name libgstges.so filetype 1 errors 4, no inode ref
root 4357 inode 3927088 errors 2001, no inode item, link count wrong
.. snip ...


ERROR: errors found in fs roots
found 63096352768 bytes used, error(s) found
total csum bytes: 57926864
total tree bytes: 3777855488
total fs tree bytes: 3570597888
total extent tree bytes: 134873088
btree space waste bytes: 801139744
file data blocks allocated: 229023404032
 referenced 215020417024
```

fstab:

```
UUID=0cbf5d8d-2c36-437d-b7e5-984f60ed315a /               btrfs   defaults,subvol=@ 0       0
# /.snapshots was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0cbf5d8d-2c36-437d-b7e5-984f60ed315a /.snapshots     btrfs   defaults,subvol=@.snapshots 0       0
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=57C6-8B0C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=a26d3dd4-ced3-48eb-b61a-ccf5e9fe4106 /home           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home 0       0
# /root was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0cbf5d8d-2c36-437d-b7e5-984f60ed315a /root           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@root 0       0
# /srv was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0cbf5d8d-2c36-437d-b7e5-984f60ed315a /srv            btrfs   defaults,subvol=@srv 0       0
# /tmp was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=8c9cc344-d720-4127-b34e-ad40c111e025 /tmp            btrfs   defaults,subvol=@tmp 0       0
# /usr/local was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0cbf5d8d-2c36-437d-b7e5-984f60ed315a /usr/local      btrfs   defaults,subvol=@usr@local 0       0
# /var was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=22f95418-090d-43a6-9399-354da3df8436 /var            btrfs   defaults,subvol=@var 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=48f727b6-65a1-4a7b-9642-fb45fdd3dfd4 none            swap    sw              0       0
# /var/lib/gdm3 was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0cbf5d8d-2c36-437d-b7e5-984f60ed315a /var/lib/gdm3   btrfs   defaults,subvol=@var@lib@gdm3 0       0

# /var/lib/AccountsService was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0cbf5d8d-2c36-437d-b7e5-984f60ed315a /var/lib/AccountsService   btrfs   defaults,subvol=@var@lib@AccountsService 0       0
```

I have also run smartctl -x /dev/sea the output being okay except for Airflow temperature.

I was able to get the dmesg output

dmesg output [dmesg output](https://pastebin.com/E45HefEE)

so also smartctl output on my drive [smartctl output](https://pastebin.com/Le7kE6tT)

The issue does seem similar with this question posted here: [enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/725826/file-system-goes-read-only-on-nvme-ssd-seemingly-at-random/725833#725833) except that my drive is a HDD type.

Comment: Your `dmesg` might be more helpful.

Comment: In any case, this HDD is doomed. If you need data from it, find a reputable recovery company.

Comment: are there steps I can take to fix this hdd, I already have a previous snapshot. Though this issues happen occasionally and I have to force a shut down

Comment: It looks like your drive is dying. If you feel confindent enough to nevertheless run a health check, use `SMART`-tools [see Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/S.M.A.R.T.). Anyhow make sure to move that data to a fresh HDD soon.

Comment: I added more info. can you confirm is the drive that has issues, am intending to get another one.